# ComboBox.NewText() cannot declare monodevelop

Tags: c#, combobox, mono, gtk#

I have been trying to run example code http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=T:Gtk.ComboBox , but up until now, it shows the error below:
[image: 'ComboBox' does not contain a definition for 'NewText']

I also noticed that my reference has red X with it. Is it the main reason of the error?
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is the reason for your errors, Monodevelop cannot find these references.
Check that gtk-sharp2 is install.

You do not say what platform, but for my ubuntu system, gtk-sharp is at /usr/lib/cli/gtk-sharp-2.0/gtk-sharp.dll

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I used Ubuntu 20.04. All of the references has been installed inside the folder you mentioned. But, when I pointed the cursor to the red X, it said that the assembly not found for framework .NET Framework 4.7. I also changed the framework to other framework e.g. Framework 4.8, but still cannot solve this issue.

Comment: I migrated to Ubuntu 20.04 about a year ago and had problems with Monodevelop, so I reverted back to 18.04.

Comment: Also in most of my projects I am using .Net Framework 4.8, Monodevelop 7.8.4, GTK+ 2.24.32, Mono 6.12.0.107.

Comment: Is the location for gtk-sharp at /usr/lib/cli/gtk-sharp-2.0/gtk-sharp.dll? Then, how about this location /usr/lib/mono/gac/gtk-sharp? Which is the correct one?

Comment: Perhaps you should give reinstalling Mono a try.  I use the mono-project.com repository rather than the one from ubuntu and I always install package mono-complete rather than just mono-devel.  Just follow instruction in the Download , Linux, Ubuntu page.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, @DarylG. After a while, I finally succeed in reinstalling both Mono repository and IDE.  For removing the repository, I used these sudo apt-get remove monodevelop and sudo apt-get purge monodevelop from [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124811/problems-when-removing-monodevelop). As for uninstalling the IDE, I used sudo apt remove --purge --auto-remove mono-runtime from [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/644938/how-to-completely-remove-mono).

Comment: Next, I installed repository first from [link](https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/) and followed by [link](https://www.monodevelop.com/download/) to install the IDE. Thanks a lot for your suggestion. Have a nice day.